# Combine two sql queries with no use of sql variables

Tags: sql-server, parent-child

This may sound like a strange request but with the experts we have available on this site, I know we can come up with a resolution for this.
So I have a stored procedure that looks like this http://pastebin.com/ZTgxG3SB
I'm trying to convert that to a simple sql statement without the usage of any temp tables and sql variables. I need to use the query in a tool where it only supports standard sql statements and does not support temp tables and sql variables.

In the stored proc, it accepts a SKU as an input parameter. First part of the SP collects up to 6 siblings for the given SKU and saves those in variables, then it executed the other sql where it collects store info and inventory for the original and the siblings. What I'd like to do is to collapse the two queries into one but not sure how to as my sql knowledge is limited. The idea I have is, start the second sql and in the portion where I put the sibling quantity, just have a subquery to go and select each siblings in a priority order.

This is very critical and would greatly appreciate some help with this. In fact, if you're local, I'll take you out to lunch :)

Comment: Put source as text.

Comment: Can't you create a function with your code, and then call that from your tool?

Comment: Calling a SP or a function has the same limitations unfortunately but I'm trying that.

Comment: Does it support common table expressions?

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using? Please elaborate in more details on the limitations of your tool. Does it support CTE?

Comment: Describe a task you're trying to accomlish instead of describing your solution.

Comment: You should read this before you continue littering your database with NOLOCK hints. http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/ And if you do continue that practice you need to include the WITH keyword. Omitting it has been deprecated.

Comment: I'm using sql 2014. CTE should be supported. Ivan, As I described in the original post, I need to get store info along with siblings and original sku inventory for stores.

Comment: @Eclipse, so use recursive CTE.

Comment: Haven't done anything with CTE, specially no recursive CTE. an example would be fantastic.

Comment: If you can't use functions. then you'll have to do something to `mm_fnGetHoldbackQuantity` as well

Comment: I take that back, I think function is allowed. I just tested it. so what would you suggest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a bunch of code that effectively repeats.  So you can change each of the:

```
sib1.product_code = @SIB1
```

to:

```
sib1.product_code in (SELECT SKU FROM @TempTbl WHERE RowID = 1)
```

That would eliminate the individual variable lookups and get you down to your target of two queries (one to create `@TempTbl` and then the final query).

You could take it a step further by using a [SQL Server Common Table Expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) instead of creating `@TempTbl`.

Comment: @Eclipse, if you can rewrite the query using the above suggestion it would be the first big step. The next one would be a simple one, if your "tool" supports CTE.